# How to return an Application_Model in JSON format in Zend Framework 1.11

Tags: php, zend-framework, json, zend-view

I define a variable in my view, called Student. In my view, how to I display the Student object as a JSON?

```
public function previewAction()
{
    // ... 
    $this->view->student = $student;
}
```

In my preview.phtml view, i have the following:

```
<script>
    // this doesn't return the Application_Model as a JSON object in the html       
    var studentData = <?php echo Zend_Json::encode($this->student); ?>; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around php tag

```
<script>
    // this doesn't return the Application_Model as a JSON object in the html       
    var studentData = "<?php echo Zend_Json::encode($this->student); ?>"; 
</script>
```

Comment: This will return the json results generated by php as a JavaScript string and not a js object notation.